# How can I separate out Express routes from server.js?

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, server-side-rendering, vue-ssr

I have been closely trying to follow this [Vue SSR guide](https://github.com/olegpisklov/vue-ssr-simple-setup) and in that example the author has placed his Express routes within a file called `server.js`. Simply for organisation purposes, I wish to keep my Express routes in a `router.express.js` file within my `src/router` folder instead of in the root file of `server.js`.

So this is a cutdown version of my `router.express.js` file:

```
const vueServerRenderer = require('vue-server-renderer');
const setupDevServer = require('../../build/setup-dev-server'); //webpack dev config
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

const createRenderer = (serverBundle) =>
    vueServerRenderer.createBundleRenderer(serverBundle, {
        runInNewContext: false,
        template: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../index.html'), 'utf-8')
    });

let renderer;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    setupDevServer(app, (serverBundle) => {
        renderer = createRenderer(serverBundle);
    });

} else {
    renderer = createRenderer(require('../../dist/vue-ssr-server-bundle.json'));
}

router.get('/', async function (req, res) {
    const context = {
        url: req.params['0'] || '/'
    };
    let html;
    try {
        html = await renderer.renderToString(context);
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.code === 404) {
            return res.status(404).send('404 | Page Not Found');
        }
        return res.status(500).send('500 | Internal Server Error');
    }
        res.end(html);
});

module.exports = router;
```

The problem is that I also need the `vue-server-renderer` code to be in the `server.js` file. I would then make the app `require` the `router.express.js` file so the Express routes work like this:

```
const vueServerRenderer = require('vue-server-renderer');
const setupDevServer = require('../../build/setup-dev-server'); //webpack dev config    
const app = express();

     const createRenderer = (serverBundle) =>
            vueServerRenderer.createBundleRenderer(serverBundle, {
                runInNewContext: false,
                template: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../index.html'), 'utf-8')
            });

        let renderer;

        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
            setupDevServer(app, (serverBundle) => {
                renderer = createRenderer(serverBundle);
            });

        } else {
            renderer = createRenderer(require('../../dist/vue-ssr-server-bundle.json'));
        }

    app.use(require('./router/express.router.js'));
```

Whenever I do this, I get a Webpack error stating that

> WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack
>   has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match
>   the API schema.
>    - configuration.entry['app'](https://github.com/olegpisklov/vue-ssr-simple-setup) should be a string.

If I remove the `vue-server-renderer` code from `server.js` then it runs fine. But the reason for having that code within `server.js` is so that the development environment works properly. Basically if the code is not in `server.js` then I cannot use hot-reloading or anything.

If I get rid of `router.express.js` and put all that code in `server.js` including the routes, then it all works perfectly including my development environment.

Why can I not (or rather how can I) keep my Express routes in a separate file and still have the `vue-server-renderer` stuff work?

Update: `setup-dev-server.js` file:

```
const setupDevServer = (app, onServerBundleReady) => {
    const webpack = require('webpack');
    const MFS = require('memory-fs');
    const path = require('path');
    const clientConfig = require('./webpack.client.config');
    const serverConfig = require('./webpack.ssr.config');

    // additional client entry for hot reload
    clientConfig.entry.app = ['webpack-hot-middleware/client', clientConfig.entry.app];

    const clientCompiler = webpack(clientConfig);

    // setup dev middleware
    app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(clientCompiler, {
       publicPath: clientConfig.output.publicPath,
       serverSideRender: true,
       logLevel: 'silent',
    }));

    // setup hot middleware
    app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(clientCompiler));

    // watch src files and rebuild SSR bundle
    global.console.log('Building SSR bundle...');
    const serverCompiler = webpack(serverConfig);
    const mfs = new MFS();

    serverCompiler.outputFileSystem = mfs;
    serverCompiler.watch({}, (error, stats) => {
        if (error) throw error;

        global.console.log(
            `${stats.toString({
                colors: true,
                modules: false,
                children: false,
                chunks: false,
                chunkModules: false,
            })}\n\n`
        );

        if (stats.hasErrors()) {
            console.error(stats.compilation.errors);
            throw new Error(stats.compilation.errors);
        }
        // read bundle generated by vue-ssr-webpack-plugin        
        const bundle = JSON.parse(
            mfs.readFileSync(path.join(clientConfig.output.path, 'vue-ssr-server-bundle.json'), 'utf-8')
        );
        onServerBundleReady(bundle);
    });
};

module.exports = setupDevServer;
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Inside of your 'router.express.js' file write: `module.exports = router;` at the bottom of the file.

2) Inside of your 'server.js' file write: `const router = require('./router/express.router.js');`
at the top of the file.

3) And now where you used to have `app.use(require('./router/express.router.js'));`
 replace that with `app.use(router);`

4) At the top of 'server.js' write  `const vueSsrBundle = require('../../dist/vue-ssr-server-bundle.json')`

5) Lastly replace `renderer = createRenderer(require('../../dist/vue-ssr-server-bundle.json')`
With `renderer = createRenderer(vueSsrBundle)`

EDIT the issue you are facing is on this [line](https://github.com/olegpisklov/vue-ssr-simple-setup/blob/master/config/webpack.client.config.js#L13) And probably related to the file 'app.js' or ['client-entry-js'](https://github.com/olegpisklov/vue-ssr-simple-setup/blob/master/src/client-entry.js)

Comment: Can you the code from the file called 'setup-dev-server'.

If there is a value in that file's JSON object called 'app' check if it is in quotes.

Check my answer point 5) for update.

Comment: I just updated my question to include the contents of `setup-dev-server`. I can't see a JSON object with app I don't think? The `webpack.client.config` shows entry as app like this `entry: {
  app: utils.resolve('/src/entry-client.js')
 },`

Comment: Your problem is here: https://github.com/olegpisklov/vue-ssr-simple-setup/blob/master/config/webpack.client.config.js#L13

Comment: By a process of deduction the problem is that I cannot have the `setupDevServer(app, (serverBundle) => {
                renderer = createRenderer(serverBundle);
            });

        } else {
            renderer = createRenderer(require('../dist/vue-ssr-server-bundle.json'));
        }` code in both `server.js` and `router.express.js` - it has to be in `server.js` only. So how then will the `html = await renderer.renderToString(context);` in my `router.express.js` routes ever work? Or rather how could I make them work by using `server.js`'s `renderer` instead of its own?